# Querying in Dexie returns nothing when offset and limit are defined

Tags: javascript, indexeddb, dexie

Dexie noob here. I'm trying to use Dexie.js to get some data out of IndexedDB. I want to get the data in batches (think pagination) and it seems that only the first query is working.

Here's the data:

```
db.friends.bulkAdd([
  {name: "David", age: 42},
  {name: "Neil", age: 37},
  {name: "Freddie", age: 36},
  {name: "Elvis", age: 56},
  {name: "Calvin", age: 22},
]);
```

And here's query #1:

```
db.friends
.orderBy('age')
.limit(2)
.offset(0)
.toArray()
.then(function(result) {
  // Works as expected!
});
```

And query #2 which returns an empty `[]`:

```
db.friends
.orderBy('age')
.limit(2)
.offset(2)
.toArray()
.then(function(result) {
  // result is []
});
```

If I leave `limit(2)` out from query #2 the query works as expected, but `offset()` and `limit()` together don't seem to work.

What am I doing wrong here? I'm probably just missing something very basic in how Dexie or IndexedDB works but can anyone help me out?

Here's [a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ckdaw/a6cLtu7n/) to test this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the jsfiddle. I can agree I found it strange at first when I read it. Then I realized the reason is the order of offset() and limit(). In your sample you are using limit() before offset(), which basically means:

1. Limit the result to 2 items only.
2. From that collection of 2 items, set an offset of 2, which leads to zero results.

So the solution is to switch the order of limit and offset - use offset first and then apply a limit on that collection.

Comment: Thanks a lot David, that solves the problem! I was sure there was something simple wrong with my code but I didn't expect it was this simple :)